# localStorage.getItem not working to change the styling of the navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, next.js

So I am trying to alternate between light and dark theme in the website I'm making using Bootstrap. Things are working great but the problem is that the browser doesn't "remember" the theme it was on after refreshing the website even though it should retrieve the theme whenever the component gets rendered.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Link from "next/link"
export default function Navbar() {
    const localTheme = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : true
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(localTheme);
    useEffect(() => localStorage.setItem("theme", theme), [theme])
    return (
        <header>
            <nav className={theme ? "navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light py-3" : "navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark py-3"}>
                <--Rest of Navbar--!>
                        <div className="form-check form-switch ms-3">
                        <input onClick={() => setTheme(!theme)} className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault"/>
                        <label className="form-check-label fw-bold" htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault" style={theme ? {color: "black"} : {color:"white"}}>{theme ? "Light" : "Dark"} Theme</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Here is a pic of the local storage after switching to the dark theme, it remembers that value but whenever I refresh the page the navbar theme turns light[image]

Comment: plz add more details. can you see the theme value in the local storage? in chorme devtools go to the application tab and check over there.

Comment: @Itaywazana my bad, should have added a picture. Yeah it retrieves the theme value properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is working example:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const defaultTheme = "light";

export default function Navbar() {
  const localTheme =
    typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? localStorage.getItem("theme") || defaultTheme
      : defaultTheme;

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(localTheme);
  console.log(`theme`, theme);

  useEffect(() => localStorage.setItem("theme", theme), [theme]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Current theme is: {theme}</div>
      <input
        onClick={() => setTheme(theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light")}
        type="checkbox"
        checked={theme === "dark"}
      />
      <label style={theme === "dark" ? { color: "black" } : { color: "white" }}>
        {theme === "light" ? "Light" : "Dark"} Theme
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately, same thing.

Comment: Updated answer .